# Build Relations Yii

Tags: yii

Для чего на странице генерации модели в Yii нужен чекбокс "Build Relations" и что он делает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создает связи в ORM-моделях в соответствии с внешними ключами таблиц в БД

Comment: А можно подробнее?
Или, может, есть какая - нибудь статья на русском?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr

Для InnoDB таблиц при наличии внешних ключей и созданных ORM-ок таблиц, куда ведут внешние ключи, на основании этих же FOREIGN KEY's генерируется метод relations()